# C Sharp Object creating and referencing only 1 object in another class

Tags: c#, class, associations, reference

I need to implement 1..* and 1..1 relationships in a store scenario application.(Classes: Member, Order, OrderLine, Product, Program, User) How do i go about a 1 user only having 1 Order that can have many OrderLines (preferably using a List structure?

This is my User class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class User
    {

        private string ffName;
        private string llName;
        private int id = 0;

        //Constructor
        public User(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            fName = firstName;
            lName = lastName;
        }
        public User() {}

        //Overrides
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj.ToString() == this.ToString();
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.ToString().GetHashCode();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string myUser;
            myUser = string.Format("First Name: {0}; Last Name: {1}", fName, lName);
            return myUser;     
        }

        // Properties
        public string fName
        {
            get
            {
                return ffName;
            }
            set
            {
                ffName = value;
            }
        }
        public string lName
        {
            get
            {
                return llName;
            }
            set
            {
                llName = value;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: 1:1 would not use a list.  1:* would.  Simple as that.  Each entity has one of these mapping relationships with other entities it is connected to, and each relationship is potentially different.  So User:Order is 1:1, but Order:OrderLine is 1:*.  Are you using entity framework, some other ORM, or creating your own mapping/repository code?

Comment: I don't think he is using EF since he defined his user class

Comment: @Boomer: EF 4.1 supports code-first with POCOs.  Tho the overridden GetHashCode and Equals are a little strange.  I was thinking the best resource would be a tutorial on whatever framework he's using, since this would be the first thing that got covered...

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: I see know what u mean :P

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham the overridden GetHashCode and Equals were a requirement by my professor. It had something to do with comparing the object themselves and not the references. As for the relationships, i know that user:order is 1:1 and Order:Orderline is 1:* but i have no idea what entity framework, or what some other ORM is.

As for the

Comment: @Troy: Yes, what the professor said is accurate, but in common practice I don't usually check equality of whole entity objects - I tend to check for matches on individual fields, and those fields that change per query.  As for the ORM question - how are you talking to the DB?  How are you reading/writing these objects to or from the DB?  Or have you not gotten there yet?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I think Troy is learning to walk first. Troy, one thing you will learn is the way you do things in school may not be the way you do them in the real world, it's just not economical. An ORM is tool that takes relationships and builds the approriate object model.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan Well the ORM tool sounds like it would be useful here. I am not connecting to the DB at this time. The console app just has to create each one and display it. Its not hard to create each one i just dont understand how to get the relationship to work with 1..* or 1..1. If i create an Order i can always create another order.

Comment: @Troy: I've written an answer that attempts to address your most recent comment

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the `Order` and the `OrderLine` class as:

```
class OrderLine
{
      //some code
}


class Order
{
     List<OrderLine> lstOrderLine;

     //some code
}
```

Then add the `Order` class to your user class.

Comment: +1; This answers what was asked.  I have a feeling the OP is going to have a lot more questions after this, tho...

Answer (score 1):

You can have an Order class and an OrderLine class. The Order class will have a List of OrderLines and the User class can have a Order member.

Something like:

```
public class User
    {

        private string ffName;
        private string llName;
        private int id = 0;
        private Order order = null;

        //Constructor
        public User(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            fName = firstName;
            lName = lastName;
        }
...
}

public class Order
{
 List<OrderLine> orderLines = null;
}

public class OrderLine
{
}
```

Comment: Does that mean a user will only make zero or one order? What if they return to buy again?

Comment: @ccozad - I had the same question, but the OP says *How do i go about a 1 user only having 1 Order that can have many OrderLines*, so I just stuck w/ answering the question.

Comment: Sticking to the spec, I can respect that :-)

Comment: You are correct. System isn't going to be keeping track of the sale unless their a member. User is a random person that is buying. Thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Removed snarkyness and attitude :)

First you need an order (hint you are going to need a class for that). Now the order needs to be attched to a user. So add a field of type User. That takes care of one order one user. (Note that a user can make more than one order)

So now you order is missing lines. Add another member variable that is a list of line types. Now in your order you need to add methods to add, remove and query order lines.

Edit: The question was raised what was meant by "add a field". Add a field means add a property or private member. When you are doing this you are doing the technical term of composition. Composition is commonly explained as a "has a" relationship. So an order "has a user" and "has a list of order lines"

```
Class User()
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName {get; set; }
    public int id { get; set;}
}

Class OrderLine()
{

}

Class Order()
{
    private List<OrderLine> orderLines;
    public User submitter { get; set;}

    public Order()
    {
         orderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
    }

    public void AddOrderLine(OrderLine newOrderLine)
    {
         this.orderLines.Add(newOrderLine);
    }

    public IList<OrderLine> GetOrderLines()
    { 
         return this.orderLines;
    }
}
```

Example

```
User customer1 = new User();
// Initialize customer1 values...
Order someOrder = new Order();
someOrder.submitter = customer1;
someOrder.AddOrderLine(new OrderLine());
```

EDIT: Changed Member class to User class

Comment: What do you mean add a field of type User? Sorry im a bit new with this. Also the member had nothing to do with the order other than the member can sell products. To buy the products you just need to be a user. This is deffinitally alot of help already though. I appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry for using different terminology in the description vs the code snippets. I mean add a field to mean add a property of private variable of that type within the class. The technical term is composition. Composition means the relationship "has a". When you add a variable you are making a "has a..." statement. So an order "has a user" and "has a list of lines", as evidenced by the property and private variable.

Comment: Also changed Member class to User class to match description.

Answer (score 0):

Your most recent comment cleared up your question:

> Its not hard to create each one i just dont understand how to get the relationship to work with 1..* or 1..1. If i create an Order i can always create another order

So, let's talk about the types of relationships.

**Relationship types**

Relationship types don't talk about absolute numbers of entities in the system.  They just talk about numbers of entities *in relation* to other entities.

**1:1 Relationship**

This means that the two entity types must exist in pairs.  If one entity of type A exists, then only one entity of type B can exist.  For example, your `User` and `Order`.  An order can't exist without a `User`, and a `User` can only have one `Order`.  This doesn't mean there is only one `User` - **there could be 42 users**.  This just means that if an `Order` exists, a `User` must also exist, and that the `User` can only have one `Order`.

There is a strict and less strict version of this.  Technically, I just described something like a 1:{0 or 1} relationship.  In a real 1:1 relationship you would *require* that the `Order` exists if the `User` exists.  Neither could exist if the other didn't exist.  However this constraint is usually relaxed when talking about relational databases (but only in one direction - in this case you still can't have an `Order` without a `User`).

You can model this relationship with code like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    // You could put a reference here back to the User if you want...
}
```

Note that it is a bit weird to only support only one `Order` for a `User`.  It makes more sense to make it `1:*`.  But if that is a requirement of your assignment, then this is how you'd model it.

**1:* Relationship**

This is similar to the 1:1 relationship.  But it relaxes some of the restrictions so that if an entity of type A exists, then any number (including zero) of type B can exist.  The example is the `Order` and `OrderLine`.  Again, there is no restriction on how many of either entity type exist.  **There could be 57 orders** in the system.  You just can't have an `OrderLine` without an `Order`, and there could be multiple `OrderLine`s per `Order`.

You can model this relationship with code like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    // You could put a reference here back to the Order if you want...
}
```

**Enforcing relational concepts in code**

I can't speak for your assignment, so make sure you back up what I am saying here against what your assignment requires.

You should not try to *enforce* basic relational concepts like these in code.  The database is better at it, has better (declarative) language to describe the relationships, and is going to be your ultimate source of data for the system.

Instead, you should just do a soft model that follows the relationships (as the code samples above do), and let the database do the real policing of those constraints.

Examples:

- You should not try to restrict construction of `Order` types in code, and you shouldn't require a `User` to exist to construct an `Order` (as code entities).
- You should not require an `Order` to exist to create an `OrderLine` (as code entities).

Trying to put these sorts of restrictions in code buys you nothing.  When you persist the entities to the database, the database will ensure these relationships for you (assuming you've set it up correctly, which you will learn to do).  Your error will be caught, and you'll learn habits that avoid these types of errors very quickly.

Trying to put these sorts of restrictions in code hurts you.  It will be harder to write your program, and it will be harder to write unit tests for your code.

For example, consider an algorithm or test that compares `OrderLine` values.  Maybe you want it to compare to a *hypothetical* `OrderLine`.  If you had relational restrictions in place in your code, you'd also have to create a hypothetical `Order` and `User`.  Would you also compare the hypothetical `User` and `Order` to the real ones?  What if your algorithm shouldn't care what `User` or `Order` it originated from?  If you're not going to compare them, why bother creating them to begin with?

So: Don't worry about it.  Softly model your relationships so that it is easy to navigate between your objects, and let the database do your strict relationship validations for you.

Comment: Note that I left my code samples as bare bones as absolutely possible.  You'd add the appropriate per-entity fields as *properties* on each entity type.  E.g. a `User` might also have a `FirstName` and `LastName` field.